# Security against IP Spoofing without consulting network administrator

Tags: ip-spoofing

I was wondering that if there is a Local Area Network and one public IP,through which various clients connect(which have been allocated private IP's).Suppose one of the clients spoofs his IP to try to launch an attack against a server(say Google).Does there exist a way that Google uses to secure itself against such attacks,without the help of network administrator.

Comment: Normally ISP's will protect it, to only allow outbound traffic from IP ranges that they own.  Are these the network administrators you talk about?

For internal networks, it would also be done with routers / switch ACL's (Access Control Lists).  If you don't have access to the network equipment, it's difficult to see where the packet really originated form.

Comment: @m1ke,I am talking whether there is a way that a web server can protect himself from such attacks without you know consulting network administrator.

Comment: Google is supposed to secure itself against what? The attack or a spoofed address? You seem to be confusing the two ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances, the NAT / PAT rules on the router will change the source IP address to its own (public) address.  This is done by the router/gateway itself, and can not be set by a client (unless [mis]configured to do so).

The target webserver will still get packets from the real (public) IP address.